# Prove that a set is closed in different norms

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, normed-spaces

I am trying to solve the following:
Let p $\in [1,\infty].$ Prove the following sentences:

1. U is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if and only if U is open in $\mathbb{R}_{p}^{n}$
2. U is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if and only if U is closed in $\mathbb{R}_{p}^{n}$

This is a problem from an Real Analysis book, and aparently $\mathbb{R}_{p}^{n}$ is just $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with p-norm. I'm a little confused, I usually know how to prove that a set is closed or open, but this time I don't know how the norms affect the statement. I can only think that $\mathbb{R}^n$ works with the Euclidean norm and it is quite clear that it is true since this norm is a particular case of the p-norm when p=2.

I would appreciate a hint if anyone knows how to solve it. Thank you(:

Comment: One method to approach this is to show that all $p$-norms on $\mathbb R^n$ are equivalent norms. This can be shown to be a consequence of the fact that $\mathbb R^n$ is finite-dimensional over $\mathbb R$. (In fact, all norms on a finite-dimensional space are equivalent.)

Then one can show that if $\| \cdot \|_\alpha$ is equivalent to $\| \cdot \|_\beta$ as norms on $X$, then $U \subseteq X$ is open in $\| \cdot \|_\alpha$ iff it is open in $\| \cdot \|_\beta$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you already seen an example in your book that says: *The identity $\operatorname{id} : \mathbb R^n_p \to \mathbb R^n_r$ is a continuous function for every $p,r \in [1,\infty]$*. Use this, and the fact that $f : X \to Y$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}(A)$ is open (or closed) for every open (or closed) set $A \subseteq Y$.